# javascript code only work once, when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Hi I have this HTML code:

```
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <%= link_to "Articulos", articulos_path, id: "ajax_articulos" %>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

and whenever someone click on #ajax_articulos I want to trigger:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#ajax_articulos" ).click(function() {
      alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    });
});
```

My problem is that it only works at first when the page is loaded. Once the page is loaded if I click again it will not work.

How could I make that action work again even when used without having to refresh the page ?

Comment: If you are talking about some AJAX scenario here, that dynamically switches out parts of the DOM, then go look into _event delegation_.

Comment: The code seems correct.
Have you checked "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs." on the alert box on your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Ruby On Rails are you using?

If you're using RoR 5 or above with turbolinks you need do something like this:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('.some_parent_class').on('click', '#ajax_articulos', function() { 
      //Handler...
  }
})
```

Comment: duuuuude I spent so much time on this. I even went crazy on doing insane AJAX call. I love you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this event using the jquery .on():

```
$(function() {
  $('.some_parent_class').on('click', '#ajax_articulos', function() { 
      //Handler...
  }
})
```

[Jquery .on() function](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Same problem works only once. I just do not want to setup AJAX call for that